# Any gold card perks?

Tags: hearthstone

If I create a golden card, are there any special perks in battle? I am just wondering since I am planning to level Anduin to 15 and get the golden Mind Blast and I want to know if there are any perks. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The only differences between a gold card and a regular card are its appearance and dust costs (for expert set cards). Gold cards that create other cards will create the gold version- a gold mind vision will create gold copies for example- but again this effect is purely cosmetic.

Using an entirely gold deck will get you a golden coin when you go second, instead of the regular coin.

Aside from looking cool, gold cards can be useful in deck testing. Using a gold copy and a regular copy of a card allows you to tell which copy is which. If you keep track of how often you see the gold one, you get an idea of how often you'd draw that card if you only had one copy in your deck.

Comment: Two other minor effects - firstly, having a deck where all of your cards are golden will give you a golden Coin (if you go second). Secondly, if you have a golden card which can create another card then the generated card will also be golden (for example, a golden Wild Growth [Druid] gives you +1 mana crystal, but will create the golden version of Excess Mana if you have 10 mana already)

Comment: I mentioned the creating golden cards but forgot about the gold coin. I'll edit that in.

Comment: I have a normal and a golden Savannah Highmane in my deck, and from experience I've noticed people are more inclined to insta-remove the golden highmane. I think (some) players assume that your golden cards are the main staple of your deck. If I have both, I'll use my golden highmane if I'm hoping to goat my enemy into playing a high level removal/poly/hex. Maybe this is a subconscious reaction, because they draw more attention.

Answer (score 17):

The argument [has been made](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/26jfqy/this_golden_card_is_weaker_than_its_normal_version/) that gold cards could actually hurt you in the case where you have a golden card and a non golden card of the same card in a deck.  If your opponent thought steals you and sees one of them, then you played the other, they now know you have another of that card in your deck.

Comment: Even if it wasn't Gold, they'd still have seen the second copy, so they would know it was there.

Comment: If the second card was drawn after seeing your hand then you playing one that was different than the one they saw would confirm you had two (and that you still have one in your hand, the one they initially saw).  Of course you could avoid this problem by just making sure to play the one that they saw and waiting to play the one you drew that they don't know about second.

Comment: I actually strongly agree with this, playing one gold and one non gold in your deck in actual play can only hurt you.

Comment: Another thing to consider is the correlation between skill and golden cards. While some newbs will have gold cards it is more likely they have been playing a while and are quite skilled. This is more important while ranking back up after a reset. I avoid all gold cards and use the blue card back for this reason. It does not hurt mechanically but may cause 1-2% of players to underestimate me.

Comment: But if your thoughtsteal is a golden card, you'll always get golden cards back. So what happens if your thoughtsteal isn't golden? Do you then get the enemy's cards *as they are* (i.e. it's golden if the enemy has the golden version), or do you always get a regular card (i.e. because you played a *regular* thoughtsteal)?

Answer (score 12):

Other than looking cool, Golden cards hold no benefit.

They are however worth significantly more if you want to turn them into dust

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to another good answers, looking Golden Soulbounded cards can tell you an estimate of opponent level. By example, if your opponent has a Golden StormWind Champion, your opponent is level 59/60 with Paladin class!

http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Paladin#Level_11-60

Comment: I have to pay attention to my opponent's decks more...